# Javascript: shortcut syntax for conditional check?

Tags: javascript, syntax, shortcut

Say I have a function that needs to check for a match with one of two different values. However, the input is very complicated:

```
function checker(id, value){
  if (this.state.users[id].items[value].name === 'onething ' ||
    this.state.users[id].items[value].name === 'theotherthing ' ){
    // my action
  }
}
```

What I end up doing is this:

```
function checker(id, value){
  var name = this.state.users[id].items[value].name
  if (name === 'onething ' || name === 'theotherthing '){
    // my action
  }
}
```

Is there any way to do something like this:

```
function checker(id, value){
  if (this.state.users[id].items[value].name === 'onething ' || 'theotherthing '){
    // my action
  }
}
```

Obviously the second method takes less typing and is easier to refactor than the first one. How do they compare memory/speed wise?

Comment: third ide like me , but not for javascipt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ECMAScript 2016 you can do something like:

```
if (['onething ','theotherthing'].includes(this.state.users[id].items[value].name)) {
    //do stuff
}
```

The statement is composed of the following parts:

1. the if statement (obviously)
2. an array definition: `['onething ','theotherthing']`
3. calling the method `includes()` on the previously defined array.

In javascript an array is an object that has methods like any other object. One of those methods is `includes()` which checks that the argument is contained inside the array. The return type of this method is boolean so it's directly evaluated by the if statement without any casting

More about `includes()`  method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: I like this answer the best, although it's doing basically the same thing as @nina's answer, just with the new ES6 `.includes`. Could you edit this to explain for beginners what this is doing and how it works?

Comment: i'll give it a try

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and test against `-1`

```
if (['onething ', 'theotherthing '].indexOf(this.state.users[id].items[value].name ) !== -1){
```

Comment: or a simple regex, but i belive not he wants

Comment: Does this only work with arrays? It looks like your answer is missing the `.name` part. (I just made up the example for this question, I'm looking for something that will apply generally)

Comment: @Life4ants, right, the part was missing, but you get the idea of the pattern. you could put all string into the array and check with indexOf.

Answer (score 0):

You could use object notation:

```
if (this.state.users[id].items in {"onething ":1, "theotherthing ":1}){
```

Or, a regular expression could also work -- shorter, but less efficient:

```
if (/onething |theotherthing /.test(this.state.users[id].items)){
```